# lodash: get an object value from an object array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object array like the following. Each object in the array has an `instructors` field which is also an array. How can I get all email fields from this object array via lodash?

Do I need to use a double _.map function? I can run a foreach in the object and then another foreach in the instructors but I don't think that's very elegant. I can't wrap my head around getting values from object arrays that contain other array fields. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[
{
    'title': 'New Class',
    'instructors': [
        {
            'email': 'someemail@gmail.com'
        },
        {
            'email': 'anotheremail@gmail.com'
        }    
    ]
},
{
    'title': 'New Class 2',
    'instructors': [
        {
            'email': 'someemail@gmail.com'
        },
        {
            'email': 'anotheremail@gmail.com'
        }    
    ]
}
```

];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to use a double _.map function?

That's one solution. You believe you are looking for [`flatMap`](https://lodash.com/docs#flatMap):

```js
var classes = [{
  'title': 'New Class',
  'instructors': [{
    'email': 'someemail@gmail.com'
  }, {
    'email': 'anotheremail@gmail.com'
  }]
}, {
  'title': 'New Class 2',
  'instructors': [{
    'email': 'someemail@gmail.com'
  }, {
    'email': 'anotheremail@gmail.com'
  }]
}];

var emails = _.flatMap(classes, function(cls) {
  return _.map(cls.instructors, 'email');
});

document.querySelector('#out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(emails, null, 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.6.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

So you know, the vanilla method is quite short too:

```
var out = arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
  return p.concat(c.instructors.map(function (instructor) {
    return instructor.email;
  }));
}, []);
```

Comment: Nice solution, we over-use lodash way to often without thinking native, compatible until **IE9**

Comment: @deKajoo, I think you meant "from IE9" :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
var allEmails = [];

_.each(myArray, function(obj) {
  _.each(obj.instructors, function(instructor) {
    allEmails.push(instructor.email);
  }, this);
}, this);

return allEmails;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k4uahqkk/1/

A more elegant solution using `_.reduce` and `_.map` would be :

```
_.reduce(myArray, function(result, value, key) {
    return result.concat(_.map(value.instructors, 'email'));
}, []);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z1tg4tro/4/

edit: `_.pluck` since v4.x is deprecated, use `_.map` instead.